# ibm worklight console asking for credentials

Tags: eclipse, console, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to run my first worklight application. after building it when i'm trying to start the worklight console from eclipse the work light console page opens and is asking me from userid and password. I tried the demo and my current windows credentials. Both dint work.

Apart from installing worklight in eclipse are we supposed to configure anything else? or do we have any default username and password for the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your user registry in your server.xml file (on Liberty profile) or your repository configuration on WAS. On a clean  install on a liberty profile instance, try admin/admin.